# Refresh a part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

i have few grid views inside of a main div and i need to refresh the main div with JavaScript every 1 second.

I don't want to use ajax with timer and triggers because while scrolling in the page i am having "jumps" - a known issue. (or not ?)

as you can see in the grid views i have pictures that are taking from the DB.
so the goal is to get the newest pictures by refresh it every 1 second.
Can i do this with JavaScript ?
it would be nice if i will have some fade in fade out effect as well !!

```
<div id="Main">

<div id="Grid1">

<asp:GridView ID="GridBox1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">     
<Columns>
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image_path" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Pic/{0}" HeaderText="pic">
<ControlStyle Height="200px" Width="200px" />
</asp:ImageField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</div>


<div id="Grid2">

<asp:GridView ID="GridBox2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">     
<Columns>
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image_path" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Pic/{0}" HeaderText="pic">
<ControlStyle Height="200px" Width="200px" />
</asp:ImageField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very expensive to poll every one second. I recommend you use a push technology leveraging web sockets instead, e.g., the excellent library [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it
>   incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your
>   applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability
>   to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as
>   it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables
>   bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR
>   will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and
>   gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it
>   isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server
>   to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers
>   from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as
>   adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect
>   events, grouping connections, authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think Gilad is quite ready for SignalR though it is relatively painless to setup. Alternatively you could use an .